# Can I define a variable through user input inside the brackets/parameters of an array AFTER defining the array?

Tags: c, arrays, variables, initialization, declaration

For example, can I do this:

```
int i, number_of_values, variable[i];
printf("Enter the number of values you would like to insert: \n");
scanf("%d", &number_of_arrays);
for (i=0; i<number_of_values; i++)
```

Instead of using a method like this:

```
printf("Enter the number of values you would like to insert: \n");
scanf("%d", &number_of_values);
int variable[no_of_values];
```

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, have you tried?

Comment: Why the need for it?

Comment: This is exactly why dynamic memory allocation exists. Look up on `malloc` and family

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array is just a chunk of contiguous memory of specified size. To allocate an array you **must** specify its size.
However, there are instances where you may not know the size required in advance. For those situations, we have dynamic memory malloc.
You may allocate the required memory at run-time using [malloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc).

```
int* a;
a=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*required_size);
```

And then access this memory as easily as you did for array e.g. `a[i]` 
or by dereferencing e.g. `*(a + i)`

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible?

**No**, because variable `i` is uninitialized. In C language, used uninitialized auto variable invoke undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This line will give you an error:

```
int i, number_of_values, variable[i];
```

The compiler don't know how much memory to reserve for the array `variable[i]`, because he don't know a value for `i`.
Only chance is dynamic memory allocation.